# Add Margin to using Sass mixins in bootstrap

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

I have a page that has a bunch of Section tags in it and I have a my-5 class on each one. Rather than repeating that every time I'd love to see if I could use a Sass Mixin to apply the my-5 css automatically to the Section tag so I could simply turn this

```
<section class="my-5">
```

into this

```
<section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use SASS `@extend` inside the `section` rule...

```
section {
   @extend .my-5;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/6ziZAFqFJj